# Disabling overcommit hook (with --run parameter)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-overcommit

I'm using the [overcommit gem](https://github.com/brigade/overcommit) to take care of my git pre-commit hooks, and I'm thinking about using the same setup in my build using `overcommit --run`.

When commiting, it is possible to skip a hook by doing something like `SKIP=ESLint git commit`, but when trying `SKIP=ESLint overcommit --run` the ESLint hook still runs.

Is there any way to disable a single hook when using the --run parameter, but still having it run on commits?

Answer (score 1):

It took a while, but I found out the SKIP environment variable works just fine.

My problem was simply that I had added an erroneous capital letter in the plugin name and written "ESLint" in stead of "EsLint".